# Ubuntu 16.04: Bluetooth not working

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I can't detect any bluetooth devices from my laptop when I try to set up a new device. I've tried some approaches from other threads, but the problem remains as is.
Any help on how to fix / what to inspect would be appreciated.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and let you know the result.

Comment: It will work 100%, but it is a bit complicated.